# Speed up AMI and ASG Creation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, autoscaling, amazon-ami

using Ansible I create an AMI of a ubuntu instance then using this AMI to create an Launch configuration and then update and auto scaling group, is there any shortcuts I can take to speed up the ASG and AMI steps, take 10mins+

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use an EBS backed AMI instead of an Instance Store backed AMI. From the [AWS docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html#storage-for-the-root-device):

> ```
>            Amazon EBS-Backed             Amazon Instance Store-Backed
> Boot time  Usually less than 1 minute    Usually less than 5 minutes
> ```

--http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ComponentsAMIs.html#storage-for-the-root-device

Comment: OK I will give that a try, is there are particular instance size that would speed things up?

Comment: When i look at the list cloud images - http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/

 hvm:ebs 
 hvm:ebs-io1
        hvm:ebs-ssd

Comment: I don't think instance size matters that much. I believe the speed gain comes from the difference between sourcing an OS image from an EBS volume versus downloading an entire OS image from S3.

Comment: I'll buy the 5 minutes time in the document, but I've yet to see in my life any EC2 instance boot in less than 1 minute.  I suppose it depends how you define boot.  Now on Google Compute Engine I can "boot" a VM in ~23 seconds and ssh into.

Answer (score 25):

I asked a similar question via an AWS Support ticket, here was there response:

> The main time consuming process when launching up a new EC2 instance
>   is the boot process of the OS within the instance: having more or less
>   security groups/network ACLs, different amount of SSH keypairs, and
>   roles associated to the instance should have no measurable impact in
>   the time it takes for it to start up. Most of the time it takes to
>   launch an instance is consumed by the OS itself.
>
> With that in mind, allow me to go over some of the main items that
>   might consume the most time when an instance boots - for all the
>   points below I will focus exclusively on Linux from an EC2 point of
>   view:
>
> - Local filesystem mounts: if your instance needs to mount a large quantity of filesystems, this will add a little time to your boot
>     process. Depending on the filesystem types you use, you might need to
>     run a check periodically every fixed number of days - for example, on
>     Linux you might need to run fsck on an ext4 filesystem every 90 days
>     (this period can change depending on your settings), and the OS
>     automatically triggers this check when the filesystem is mounted upon
>     boot if it detects that the period has been exceeded. One strategy for
>     preventing this can be executing these checks before you create the
>     AMI you'll use to launch your new instances, so that any instances
>     launched from this AMI will have their filesystems recently checked
>     and you won't run into unexpected fsck executions when launching your
>     instances for the first time. Depending on the type of filesystem you
>     use, it may be possible to disable these periodic checks altogether,
>     but I wouldn't recommend it as they are necessary to maintain the
>     filesystem's integrity over time.
> - Remote filesystem mounts: if your instance needs to mount any remote filesystem (for example, an EFS share, or any conventional NFS share),
>     your boot process may be delayed depending on the network connectivity
>     to the server sharing this remote filesystem. In the worst case
>     scenario, if the server sharing the filesystem is offline, your boot
>     process will be interrupted until this connection times out and fails.
>     If you're mounting any remote filesystems by default when launching
>     your instances, make sure the servers sharing them are available
>     before launching your instances.
> - Regular OS initialization scripts: the largest part of the time consumed by the boot process will be taken by the starting the OS
>     services. There are two types models for this in Linux: the
>     traditional SystemV init (which starts services in a serial way, one
>     after the other), and the relatively new systemd (which is able to
>     start services in parallel, and thus decrease the boot time in some
>     circumstances). Which of these you use will depend on the Linux
>     distribution you run in your instances. For example, if you need to
>     start a DB server that might take a long time every time you boot your
>     instance, it might be worthwhile to consider systemd as it will allow
>     for the rest of the unrelated services to be launched in parallel, as
>     long as they don't have this DB server as a prerequisite.
> - User data and cloud-init scripts: these are executed after the regular OS init scripts are over. Like on the previous items, you
>     might want to check that any of these custom scripts you execute are
>     optimized so they can take the least time necessary; it's
>     recommendable to test any custom user data scripts individually to
>     measure their time before adding them to a new instance launch so you
>     can have a better idea of their impact in the overall time of the
>     instance startup. If your scripts are retrieving any files external to
>     the instance (if you download something from an S3 bucket, run an
>     automatic update of the installed packages, etc), the same
>     considerations I've mentioned of the "Remote filesystem mounts" item
>     mentioned above apply - make sure there are no network issues that
>     could slow down or prevent this connection, as this would add more
>     time to the overall startup process of your instance.
> - Instance type: instance type does affect the time it takes for the OS to finish booting. Under the same circumstances, a t2.large
>     instance will boot faster than a t2.nano simply because it has more
>     RAM, vCPUs, and a higher amount of CPU credits - all of which allow
>     the OS to execute the boot process faster. Also, if you need to
>     retrieve large amounts of data as part of the instance launch process,
>     you might want to use enhanced networking mode and EBS-optimized
>     instances to ensure you have the best bandwidth available for your
>     needs; see the links at the end of this message for more details about
>     this.
> - EBS Volume type: just like with instance type, the performance of your EBS volumes is also a factor that can impact on the overall time
>     of the instance startup times. If your instance needs to read large
>     amounts of data during the boot process from a sc1 volume (an HDD
>     volume with low performance designed for infrequently accessed data),
>     the boot process will be slower than if your instance reads the same
>     data from a PIOPS volume with a much higher performance - if your use
>     case contains a scenario where you are affected by this, you might
>     want to test different volume types to choose the one that better
>     suits your needs. Likewise, the type of your instance's root volume
>     will also impact on the boot performance, since in all cases you will
>     have to read information from it. For most cases, the default "General
>     purpose SSD" a.k.a. gp2 EBS volumes are good enough for instance root
>     volumes.
>
> Ultimately, the time taken to launch a new instance will be determined
>   by running benchmarks for your particular use case; the general
>   considerations I've mentioned above can help you reduce this time, but
>   to  determine which settings that are best for your environment you'll
>   need to test and fine tune each parameter until you reach a point
>   where the startup time suits your needs.
>
> I'm attaching a couple of links at the end of this reply with more
>   details about the items I've mentioned on this reply.
>
> I hope this information has been useful to you. Please let me know if
>   you have any questions.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Related links:
>   - EC2 instance types: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/
>   - EBS volume types: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html
>   - EBS optimized instances: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSOptimized.html
>   - Performance tips for EBS volumes: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSPerformance.html
>   - Enhancing networking mode on EC2 Linux instances: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html